# Get pictures in the source code of a web page

Tags: firefox, images

As we know, we can get the source code of a web page with Firefox. I'd want to get the pictures in the page via the source code. Is there a way for it? Or any addons of Firefox to achieve it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good add-on for Firefox named DownThemAll! that allows to download any media on a page by filtering with a regular expression. Apart from that, this question is not programming-related.

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox, without any add-ons: menu Tools » Page Info (Command-I on a Mac), tabsheet Media. This also gives you a Save As button for media that cannot be right-clicked on the site itself.

[image: Firefox Page Info]

If for some reason some tabsheets are not showing at all, then you might need to [Refresh Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings). (In my case this once happened as it was having problems signing in to Sync, showing things like *NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIPK11Token.initPassword]* in Tools » Web Developer » Browser Console. A refresh fixed that.)

Comment: Hi, your link in the reply was b0rked, fixed it and then there was a redirect from Mozilla; so, this is what it looks like now: 

[Refresh Firefox - reset add-ons and settings - Mozilla Support Community](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Procedures-to-diagnose-and-fix/Refresh-Firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings/ta-p/23405)

Comment: @Nostromov, thanks. I've only removed the erroneous suffix from the URL for now; I somehow assume that the shorter URL (pre-redirect) will be better in the future. If not, then maybe the URL in your comment will help people find it.

Answer (score 1):

Alertnatively, you could just press Ctrl-U and have a look at the source...

Comment: i have solved the problem by getting the pictures from the Temp Folder .thanks for all your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). User documentation with videos/screencasts [here](http://getfirebug.com/docs.html).

Answer (score 0):

(at least if you're on a mac), drag and drop them onto your desktop (or anywhere else).

Comment: i have solved this problem by getting the pictures from the Temp Folder.thanks for all you attention.