# Saving a web page content on a Mac

Tags: browser, safari

I've stumbled into a webpage and I want to save its contents. Logically, the contents is already on my drive. How can I figure out which temporary directory holds the contents of this specific page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there any reason you can't do File → Save As → Web Archive?

Comment: How can I export the images from a web archive?

Comment: Wfaulk is correct.  This is the normal method of handling this.

Answer (score 0):

The data should be saved in .cache files under `~/Library/Caches/Safari`. You can search them with `grep` and then drag and drop these .cache files into Safari from Finder.

Comment: It's not. Any idea?

Comment: You're on OSX, right? And it's User -> Library -> Caches -> Safari in finder, ~/Library/Caches/Safari in terminal.

Comment: Nope. Nothing there.

Answer (score 0):

The proper method would be (as wfaulk) mentioned using a webarchive from Safari.  The webarchive file appears to be a flat file that contains all the seperate files that make up the web page.

Now, how would you extract something from that?  Open the webarchive in safari, and then drag and drop, or copy and paste, or save as HTML for the pages...

Or, use the free [Web Archive Folderizer](http://www.macworld.com/article/50198/2006/04/webarchivefolderizer.html)....That utility will allow you to extract the contents of the webarchive, into a folder..

Alternatively, "Print" the web page, and choose Save as PDF from the PDF pull down...

Or, WebSucker, would allow you download the web site, or particular pages of the website...

Answer (score 0):

> How can I export the images from a web archive?

I guess opening that archive lets you right-click the images again.

However, if you know beforehand you just want to save *some* of the content, then you don't need to create such web archive first. In Firefox see menu Tools » Page Info (Command-I on a Mac), tabsheet Media. This also gives you [a Save As button](https://superuser.com/questions/38213/get-pictures-in-the-source-code-of-a-web-page/51609#51609) for media that cannot be right-clicked on the site itself.

And as a side note: if you were to save as PDF from Safari or OmniWeb, then you would have clickable links in the resulting PDF document. When doing the same from Firefox, you do *not* get such clickable links.

(And when saving as PDF, get rid of the things you don't want first: [The Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ThePrintliminator/) is your friend. And whatever you do: respect the author's rights please!)